"display-override" field in my manifest.json flagging problem
  "display_override": [
    "standalone",
    "fullscreen",
    "minimal-ui",
    "window-controls-overlay",
    "browser"
  ],

Above is a part of my manifest.json
Vscode seems to highlight it as an error. Whats wrong?
Im sure that part is the error because after taking it out, there is no detected errors in the file.

Choose only window-controls-overlay

I'm not sure you understand the display_override property. It is supposed to have an array of elements. See this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display_override

Since the question is about some valid-looking JSON being flagged as invalid, if you're suggesting that the JSON truly is invalid, it would be useful to show an example of the fixed JSON. I agree that [ "standalone", "window-controls-overlay", "browser" ] looks like a valid array.
